# Slider con animaciones Lottie envés de imagenes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Buen día, quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con un slider que estoy haciendo en mi App. Resulta que quiero usar animaciones Lottie envés de imágenes y para eso cree un adapter, lo malo es que no sé que array tengo que utilizar para almacenar mis animaciones ni que método ni que parámetros usar para poder usar las animaciones que yo quiero. Ya tengo todo listo, tengo la carpeta assest donde están mis animaciones, la librería Lottie y hasta mi layout con la etiqueta `<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView/>`

***Tambien les dejo imagenes de como es mi slider:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Imagen de donde quiero poner el método**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***SliderAdapter**

```
package com.example.gonzalo.proyecto_android_2018.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import com.example.gonzalo.proyecto_android_2018.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.slide_layout.view.*
import java.io.InputStream

class SliderAdapter(var contexto: Context):PagerAdapter()
{

private val inflador:LayoutInflater

init {
    inflador = LayoutInflater.from(contexto)
}

var slide_background:IntArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.gradient_uno, R.drawable.gradient_dos, R.drawable.gradient_tres)
var slide_image:IntArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.persona_saludando, R.drawable.ic_parada_de_autobus, R.drawable.ic_parada_de_autobus_2)
var slide_headings = arrayOf(R.string.Slide_Bienvenido,R.string.Slide_Ubicanos, R.string.Slide_Espera)
var slide_descriptions = arrayOf(R.string.Slider_description_uno, R.string.Slider_description_dos, R.string.Slider_description_tres)

var slide_videos: Array<InputStream> = arrayOf(contexto.assets.open("pollo.json"),contexto.assets.open("mapa.json"),contexto.assets.open("bus_move.json"))

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, objeto: Any) //Retorna un Boolean
        = view === objeto as (RelativeLayout)

override fun getCount() //Retorna un entero
        = slide_headings.size

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = inflador.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false)
    view.slide_relative.setBackgroundResource(slide_background[position])
    view.slide_imagen.setImageResource(slide_videos[position])
    view.slide_lbl1.setText(slide_headings[position])
    view.slide_lbl2.setText(slide_descriptions[position])

    if(position == 0){
        view.slide_point1.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point2.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point3.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
    }

    if(position == 1){
        view.slide_point1.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point2.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point3.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
    }

    if(position == 2){
        view.slide_point1.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point2.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor))
        view.slide_point3.setTextColor(contexto.resources.getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor))
    }
    container.addView(view)
    return view
}

override fun destroyItem(container:ViewGroup, position: Int, objeto: Any) {
    container.removeView(objeto as (RelativeLayout))
}

}
```

***IntroActivity**

```
package com.example.gonzalo.proyecto_android_2018.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.gonzalo.proyecto_android_2018.R
import com.example.gonzalo.proyecto_android_2018.adapter.SliderAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_intro.*

class IntroActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var slidera_adapter:SliderAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro)

    slidera_adapter = SliderAdapter(this)

    intro_viewpager.adapter = slidera_adapter

    boton_saltar.setOnClickListener({
        startActivity(Intent(this@IntroActivity, RegistrarActivity::class.java))
    })
}
}
```

***slide_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slide_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/slide_video"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"

        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="assets"
        app:lottie_fileName="pollo.json"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_lbl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/slide_video"
        android:text="Hola"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_lbl2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/slide_lbl1"
        android:text="Descripcion"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_point1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_point2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/slide_point1"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_point3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/slide_point1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***activity_intro.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.IntroActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/intro_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton_saltar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_boton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/boton_saltar"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pregunta duplicada? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/210117/como-realizar-un-slider-con-animaciones-android Te sugiero no realizar la misma pregunta varias veces, realiza tu pregunta basándote en [ask] y te aseguro obtendrás la ayuda deseada,  saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que colocar tus animaciones en la carpeta res/raw, si no la tienes creala y colocalas alli, una vez colocadas solo tienes que agregar las siguientes lineas en tu adapter:

```
        if(position == 0){
            view.slide_video.setAnimation(R.raw.tu_animacion_1);
            view.slide_video.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            view.slide_video.playAnimation();
        }

        if(position == 1){
            view.slide_video.setAnimation(R.raw.tu_animacion_2);
            view.slide_video.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            view.slide_video.playAnimation();
        }

        if(position == 2){
            view.slide_video.setAnimation(R.raw.tu_animacion_3);
            view.slide_video.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            view.slide_video.playAnimation();
        }
```

Puedes hacerlo asi o un arreglo de Int que serian id's de tus recursos.
https://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html#sample-app